# Plot function results according to a range

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot function results according to a range; for this I defined the range -

```
r = [-1:0.01:4.5]
```

and I have a file `G.m` which describe a function  -

```
function [y] = G(x)
y=(1/4)*((x^3)-4*(x^2)+7*x);
end
```

I want to examine function `G` throughout all the range `r`.

I tried `plot(r,G(r))` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
y=(1/4)*((x^3)-4*(x^2)+7*x);
```

to:

```
y=(1/4)*((x.^3)-4*(x.^2)+7*x);
```

And `plot(r,G(r))` will work for you my friend.